# Getting number of hyponym and deep in WordNet using JWNL

Tags: wordnet

I'm using JWNL library for search similarity. In the formula, hyponym count is needed. How i get number of Hyponym and Deep of synset in WordNet using JWNL ? Thanks

I have tried the code below. But when the program running there is error java heap space. My java heap space is 2 GB

```
//Method for count number of hyponym of synset
public double getHypo(Synset synset) throws JWNLException {
    double hypo = PointerUtils.getInstance().getHyponymTree(synset).toList().size();
    return hypo;
}

//Method for count deep of synset from root (deep root =1)
public double getDeep(Synset synset) throws JWNLException {
    double deep = PointerUtils.getInstance().getHypernymTree(synset).toList().size() + 1;
    return deep;
}
```

Comment: Try Google. On SO, show your efforts and then ask for help describing what not working.

Comment: I have try this .. but i'm not sure because that make error: java heap space. This for hyponym count
double hypo = PointerUtils.getInstance().getHyponymTree(w.getSense(1)).toList().size();

and this for deep
double deep= PointerUtils.getInstance().getHypernymTree(w.getSense(1)).toList().size();

Is that true ?

Comment: @fena22 Edit your question to show the code you've tried (rather than putting it in a comment). Also, if you can show a little bit more code (e.g. what exactly is `w` in each case). You might also want to say how much memory java is running with.